# I have some problem with Null Point Exception

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to create a `Uid` code and I encounter this problem about `NullPointException` :

```java
    package com.example.musicmates;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.annotations.NotNull;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.Set;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private RecyclerView postList;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private CircleImageView NavProfileImage;
private TextView NavProfileUserName;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference UsersRef;
String currentUserID;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigaition_view);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawable_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,drawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header);
        NavProfileImage = navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_image);
        NavProfileUserName = navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_full_name);


        UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                    String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                    NavProfileUserName.setText(fullname);
                    Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(NavProfileImage);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                UserMenuSelector(menuItem);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser == null){
            SendUserToLoginActivity();
        }
        else{
            CheckUserExistence();
        }
    }

    private void CheckUserExistence()
    {
        final String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_user_id))
                {
                    SendUserToSetupActivity();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void SendUserToSetupActivity() {
        Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
        setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(setupIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void UserMenuSelector(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_post:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Add new post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_home:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_friends:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Friends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_find_friends:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Find Friends", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_message:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_setting:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Setting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Log out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mAuth.signOut();
                SendUserToLoginActivity();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

> 2019-11-02 11:46:36.860 16810-16810/com.example.musicmates
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.musicmates, PID: 16810
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.musicmates/com.example.musicmates.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a
>   null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object
>   reference
>           at com.example.musicmates.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)

Comment: Could you add some code...your `MainActivity` class

Comment: drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawable_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,drawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header);
        NavProfileImage = navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_image);
        NavProfileUserName = navView.findViewById(R.id.nav_profile_full_name);

Comment: UsersRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                    String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                    NavProfileUserName.setText(fullname);
                    Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(NavProfileImage);
                }
         }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app `build.gradle`, add this to your dependencies

`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:x.x.x'` (latest version)

Add this inside `onCreate`  under this line : `navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigaition_view);`

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
         currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();   
        }else{
             finish();
             SendUserToLoginActivity();
   }
```

remove the check method from `onstart` . Clean and rebuild your project and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Hi. Where can I add if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
    //Go to login 
}
else{
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
}

Comment: Inside on Create .

Comment: also mark that in which you are getting error, i will try to solve the issue.

Comment: I just posted full code. Please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: @Kevin check please.

Comment: if you again get the error please check in which line you are getting the error.

Comment: currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

Comment: which method check?

Comment: check my answer i have changed it.

Comment: if it still give you null . clear your app and login again.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference

Comment: if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)  is the error line

Comment: did you clean the app data and then login?